# sitecore: webforms for marketers, one form, two pages

Tags: sitecore

I want to use single form for several pages like a block. Sitecore always creates a new form for a page.
How to share/reuse a form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on weather you are using WFFM 1 or 2 but it is quite similar.

Go to "Presentation/Layout details" for the item (page) that holds the form. You will find a rendering called "Form Interpreter" click this.

If you are using WFFM2 there is a "FormID" field that has your form selected. Just add a similar rendering to every page that you want the form to appear in and select the same form.

For WFFM1 there would be a parameter called "FormID" and a sitecore ID, copy this ID and the same renderings to the other pages including the parameters.

Good luck, Larre

Answer (score 0):

There's an option to select a form to copy from. See paragraph 2.3.1 "Copying an Existing Form in the Page Editor" of [this guide](http://sdn.sitecore.net/upload/sdn5/products/web_forms2/web_forms_for_marketers_v21_user_guide-a4.pdf).

Comment: Thank you. But it means you will have several copies forms as well as several reports at backoffice. I want one report. So this doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue with WFFM MVC version 8.1 (initial release)
our content editors wanted to use experience editor(page editor) and didn't want to change the datasource by going to presentation details and updating the datasource.
It doesn't need any coding

1- Copy /sitecore/layout/Renderings/Modules/Web Forms for Marketers/Mvc Form and give it a name "Custom Form"

2- Set the Data source location

[image]

3- Add the new rendering to place holder settings

/sitecore/layout/Placeholder Settings/content
[image]

my blog post
http://azadehkhojandi.blogspot.com.au/2016/01/how-to-reuse-web-forms-for-marketers.html